# Read .txt to stuct with limited number of items

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am quite new to C++ although I have worked with C# briefly and a few web-dev languages.
I have a database stored as a .txt file in a known location.
The first line of the .txt file is how many items are in the database.
I have a Struct to read all the values into as they are of the same format.

I have managed to write a piece of code which will read in the file and give me an integer value of how many items there are, I just need help reading in the data to an array of structs.

an example database is

```
3

NIKEAIRS
9
36.99

CONVERSE
12
35.20

GIFT
100
0.1
```

My struct is

```
struct Shoes{
   char Name[25];
   unsigned int Stock;
   double Price;
};
```

My code to read the number of items is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    char UserInput;

    string NumOfItems; //this will contain the data read from the file
    ifstream Database("database.txt"); //opening the file.
    if (Database.is_open()) //if the file is open
    {
        int numlines;
        getline (Database,NumOfItems);
        numlines=atoi(NumOfItems.c_str());
        cout<<numlines;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; //if the file is not open output
    cin>>UserInput;
    return 0;
}
```

Could I have some pointers on how to proceed.

Comment: through a exception if you can't open the file, and do something about it (exit for a example)

Comment: Well the first step is to read the lines for each struct - very similar to what you have done for the count (say N), but then you need to loop `N` times and read 3 entries each time...

Comment: You'll want to declare a std::vector<Shoe> to hold your shoes.

Comment: I'd overload `operator>>` for `Shoes`. And I'd name the struct `Shoe`, not `Shoes`.

Comment: @VaughnCato but JimBob hasn't told us whether his lecturer wants him to use vectors...;P

Comment: Hi again.

Thanks for the interest.
I am trying to do it with only the libraries included above, it makes it longer but it is what i'm after

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?   I know there are more efficient ways to do this,
but at least this should get you started in the right direction.  Cheers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Shoes {
    char Name[25];
    unsigned int Stock;
    double Price;
};

vector<Shoes> ShoeList;

static Shoes readShoe(std::ifstream& fs)
{
    char buffer[200];               //  temporary buffer
    Shoes s;

    fs.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));     // newline
    fs.getline(s.Name, sizeof(buffer));     // name
    fs.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));     // amt in stock
    s.Stock=atoi(buffer);
    fs.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));     // price
    s.Price=strtod(buffer, 0);

    return s;
}

int main ()
{
    char UserInput;

    string NumOfItems; //this will contain the data read from the file
    ifstream Database("database.txt"); //opening the file.
    if (Database.is_open()) //if the file is open
    {
        int numlines;
        getline (Database,NumOfItems);
        numlines=atoi(NumOfItems.c_str());
        cout<<numlines;

    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < numlines; ++i)
    {
        Shoes s = readShoe(Database);
        ShoeList.push_back(s);
        cout << "Added (Name=" << s.Name << "," << s.Stock << "," << s.Price << ") to list." << endl;
    }

    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; //if the file is not open output

    cin>>UserInput;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this, do you possibly know of a solution that does not use vectors, as I am trying to achieve this with only the 3 libraries in my original code.

Comment: @JimBob a header is not a library. `#include <vector>` does not require any additional library to be linked. But if you really fell you need to do this without vector, you could still use a c style array `Shoes* ShoeList = new Shoes[numlines]; ... ShoeList[i] = s; ... delete [] ShoeList;` but good luck with shooting yourself in the foot. Use std::vector!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numlines; ++i)
{
 Shoes sh();
 Database >> sh.Name >> sh.Stock >> sh.price;
 //do something with sh (add it to a list or a array for example
}
```